# Ebay findItemsByProduct API - determine if book is study guide

Tags: php, xml, curl, ebay-api

I am currently pulling book data from the Ebay findItemsByProduct API.

One requirement that I need to implement is to filter books which are "study guide" versions.

The issue is that the study guide and the book itself both share the same IBSN.

I went through the process of adding a book for sale on ebay, and the info is available. Example: I can mark the book as a "study guide" version.

The API call currently being made:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
&SECURITY-APPNAME=[YOUR-APP-ID]
&REST-PAYLOAD
&productId.@type=ISBN
&productId=0073378151
&itemFilter%280%29.name=ListingType
&itemFilter%280%29.value%280%29=FixedPrice
&itemFilter%280%29.value%281%29=AuctionWithBIN
&itemFilter%281%29.name=Currency
&itemFilter%281%29.value=USD
&itemFilter%282%29.name=MinQuantity
&itemFilter%282%29.value=1
&itemFilter%283%29.name=TopRatedSellerOnly
&itemFilter%283%29.value=true&itemFilter%284%29.name=Condition
&itemFilter%284%29.value=1000
&outputSelector%280%29=SellerInfo
&outputSelector%281%29=StoreInfo
&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=30
&paginationInput.pageNumber=1
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML
```

I cannot however, determine how to even pull this attribute out from the API.

Response from Ebay:

```
<findItemsByProductResponse>
  <ack>Success</ack>
  <version>1.12.0</version>
  <timestamp>2014-07-18T20:11:15.512Z</timestamp>
  <searchResult count="10">
    <item>
      <itemId>161145410493</itemId>
      <title>%% International Edition %% Paperback Hole's Essentials of Human Anatomy and Phy</title>
      <globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
      <primaryCategory>
        <categoryId>2228</categoryId>
        <categoryName>Textbooks, Education</categoryName>
      </primaryCategory>
      <galleryURL>http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mI9orcyWmrgiMXpxQG4gRfA/140.jpg</galleryURL>
      <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/International-Edition-Paperback-Holes-Essentials-Human-Anatomy-and-Phy-/161145410493?pt=US_Texbook_Education</viewItemURL>
      <productId type="ReferenceID">102861218</productId>
      <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
      <autoPay>true</autoPay>
      <location>Thailand</location>
      <country>TH</country>
      <storeInfo>
        <storeName>sevenseller777</storeName>
        <storeURL>http://stores.ebay.com/sevenseller777</storeURL>
      </storeInfo>
      <sellerInfo>
        <sellerUserName>sevenseller777</sellerUserName>
        <feedbackScore>957</feedbackScore>
        <positiveFeedbackPercent>100.0</positiveFeedbackPercent>
        <feedbackRatingStar>Purple</feedbackRatingStar>
        <topRatedSeller>true</topRatedSeller>
      </sellerInfo>
      <shippingInfo>
        <shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
        <shippingType>Free</shippingType>
        <shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
        <expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>
        <oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
        <handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
      </shippingInfo>
      <sellingStatus>
        <currentPrice currencyId="USD">40.36</currentPrice>
        <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">40.36</convertedCurrentPrice>
        <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
        <timeLeft>P17DT15H20M7S</timeLeft>
      </sellingStatus>
      <listingInfo>
        <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
        <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
        <startTime>2013-11-08T11:26:22.000Z</startTime>
        <endTime>2014-08-05T11:31:22.000Z</endTime>
        <listingType>FixedPrice</listingType>
        <gift>false</gift>
      </listingInfo>
      <returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
      <condition>
        <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
        <conditionDisplayName>Brand New</conditionDisplayName>
      </condition>
      <isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
      <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
    </item>
    <item>
      <itemId>181456305316</itemId>
      <title>*International Edition* Softcover * Hole's Essentials of Human Anatomy and Physi</title>
      <globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
      <primaryCategory>
        <categoryId>2228</categoryId>
        <categoryName>Textbooks, Education</categoryName>
      </primaryCategory>
      <galleryURL>http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mdK6dOIq_yI-Wm_tb-afKDA/140.jpg</galleryURL>
      <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/International-Edition-Softcover-Holes-Essentials-Human-Anatomy-and-Physi-/181456305316?pt=US_Texbook_Education</viewItemURL>
      <productId type="ReferenceID">102861218</productId>
      <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
      <autoPay>true</autoPay>
      <location>Thailand</location>
      <country>TH</country>
      <sellerInfo>
        <sellerUserName>textbkb2012</sellerUserName>
        <feedbackScore>369</feedbackScore>
        <positiveFeedbackPercent>99.0</positiveFeedbackPercent>
        <feedbackRatingStar>Turquoise</feedbackRatingStar>
        <topRatedSeller>true</topRatedSeller>
      </sellerInfo>
      <shippingInfo>
        <shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
        <shippingType>Free</shippingType>
        <shipToLocations>US</shipToLocations>
        <shipToLocations>CA</shipToLocations>
        <shipToLocations>AU</shipToLocations>
        <shipToLocations>JP</shipToLocations>
        <shipToLocations>Europe</shipToLocations>
        <expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>
        <oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
        <handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
      </shippingInfo>
      <sellingStatus>
        <currentPrice currencyId="USD">40.37</currentPrice>
        <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">40.37</convertedCurrentPrice>
        <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
        <timeLeft>P14DT14H34M43S</timeLeft>
      </sellingStatus>
      <listingInfo>
        <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
        <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
        <startTime>2014-07-03T10:40:58.000Z</startTime>
        <endTime>2014-08-02T10:45:58.000Z</endTime>
        <listingType>FixedPrice</listingType>
        <gift>false</gift>
      </listingInfo>
      <returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
      <condition>
        <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
        <conditionDisplayName>Brand New</conditionDisplayName>
      </condition>
      <isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
      <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
    </item>
  </searchResult>
</findItemsByProductResponse>
```

Comment: Please add to your question the response that you get back from this api call.

Comment: Please read this friendly documentation http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html#findItemsByProductInput and then work out what searchResult.item.attribute is supposed to do for this api call

Comment: I also just noticed that there was an additional parameter in my API call, so I removed it. Brandin, as for the documentation, it is not clear to me how to pull this info. I have been reviewing the docs all day.

Comment: Find the name of that class of this type of attribute you set to your own value from the documentation. Then search the documentation for that specific term. Also contact the vendor of that API for your support options.